# How to resample dates with Pandas item by item?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, resampling

My objective is to add rows in pandas in order to replace missing data with previous data and resample dates at the same time. Example : 
This is what I have :

```
date        wins    losses
2015-12-19  11         5
2015-12-20  17         8
2015-12-20  10         6
2015-12-21  15         1
2015-12-25  11         5
2015-12-26  6         10
2015-12-27  10         6
2015-12-28  4         12
2015-12-29  8         11
```

And this is what I want :

```
            wins    losses
date        
2015-12-19  11.0    5.0
2015-12-20  10.0    6.0
2015-12-21  15.0    1.0
2015-12-22  15.0    1.0
2015-12-23  15.0    1.0
2015-12-24  15.0    1.0
2015-12-25  11.0    5.0
2015-12-26  6.0     10.0
2015-12-27  10.0    6.0
2015-12-28  4.0     12.0
2015-12-29  8.0     11.0
```

And this is my code :

```
resamp = df.set_index('date').resample('D', how='last', fill_method='ffill')
```

It works !
But I want to do the same thing with 22 million lines (pandas), with different dates, and different IDs..

This dataframe contains two productID (1 and 2). I want to do the same previous exercice and keep the time serie data of every productID..

```
createdAt   productId   popularity
2015-12-01  1              5
2015-12-02  1              8
2015-12-04  1              6
2015-12-07  1              9
2015-12-01  2              5
2015-12-03  2             10
2015-12-04  2              6
2015-12-07  2             12
2015-12-09  2             11
```

This is my code :

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['createdAt'])
df.set_index('date').resample('D', how='last', fill_method='ffill')
```

This is what I have if I use the same code ! I don't want a groupby with my dates.

```
            createdAt   productId   popularity
date            
2015-12-01  2015-12-01  2              5
2015-12-02  2015-12-02  2              5
2015-12-03  2015-12-03  2             10
2015-12-04  2015-12-04  2              6
2015-12-05  2015-12-05  2              6
2015-12-06  2015-12-06  2              6
2015-12-07  2015-12-07  2             12
2015-12-08  2015-12-08  2             12
2015-12-09  2015-12-09  2             11
```

This is what I want !

```
createdAt   productId   popularity
2015-12-01  1               5
2015-12-02  1               8
2015-12-03  1               8
2015-12-04  1               6
2015-12-05  1               6
2015-12-06  1               6
2015-12-07  1               9
2015-12-01  2               5
2015-12-02  2               5
2015-12-03  2              10
2015-12-04  2               6
2015-12-05  2               6
2015-12-06  2               6
2015-12-07  2              12
2015-12-08  2              12
2015-12-09  2              11
```

What to do ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should works :)

```
print df.set_index('date').groupby('productId', group_keys=False).apply(lambda   
df: df.resample('D').ffill()).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

This produces what you said you wanted.

```
print df.groupby('productId', group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df.resample('D').ffill()).reset_index()

    createdAt  productId  popularity
0  2015-12-01          1           5
1  2015-12-02          1           8
2  2015-12-03          1           8
3  2015-12-04          1           6
4  2015-12-05          1           6
5  2015-12-06          1           6
6  2015-12-07          1           9
7  2015-12-01          2           5
8  2015-12-02          2           5
9  2015-12-03          2          10
10 2015-12-04          2           6
11 2015-12-05          2           6
12 2015-12-06          2           6
13 2015-12-07          2          12
14 2015-12-08          2          12
15 2015-12-09          2          11
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works but as said Heerr König I needed to add "df.set_index('date')".. I have a new problem.. I have this error message : "ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit". In your view, what is the problem ? Thank you again